# Turn on Security Essentials on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: ms-security-essentials

Is it possible to turn on microsoft security essentials on windows server 2008 r2? clicking on the application icon shows a message that it has been turned off and to see security and maintenance to enable. however there are no options in security and maintenance for security essentials.

Comment: Did you install MSE? Windows Server 2008 R2 isn't a supported OS, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Security Essentials is only supported on [Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download). There are hacks to get around this, however it's not supported by Microsoft.